# mysqldump does not work in java

Tags: java, mysql

I am using this command line argument to clone a database :-

```
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqldump"  -u root -ppass -d oldDB | mysql -u root -ppass -DnewDB
```

This piece works fine when directly pasted into command line. But, when I tried running this argument using java, it did not work. My java code is :-

```
 String serverLoc = "C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.6\\";
 String a = "\"" + serverLoc + "bin\\mysqldump\" " ;
 String cmd = a + "-u root -ppass -d oldDB | mysql -u root -ppass -DnewDB";

 Process runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd);
 int processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor();

 if (processComplete == 0) {
     System.out.println("SUCCESS");
 } else {
     System.out.println("ERROR");
 }

 //OUTPUT : ERROR
```

Exception handling not shown as no stack trace is printed. When I print `cmd`, the above desired string is printed which works when pasted into command line. Please help me solve this dilemma.

Comment: Have you tried this  `String cmd = a + "-u root -p pass -d oldDB | mysql -u root -p pass -D newDB";` &  `String cmd = a + "-uroot -ppass -doldDB | mysql -uroot -ppass -DnewDB";`?

Comment: Try reading the errorStream, and see what is says. You can check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26427333/shell-command-not-executed/26427532#26427532) too. If its a deadlock, you can find the cause there.

Comment: @Daniel I tried printing stack trace but the code does not even go to the catch block

Comment: You might want to use liquibase instead, which would offer a Java interface...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe on windows you have to call the command this way:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd " + ecuteCmd)
```

Also I think it is better to use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String[])` method

```
    String prog = "C:\\program files\\server\\xampp\\mysql\\bin\\mysql";
    String user = "-uroot";
    String pass = "-ppass";
    Process runtimeProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { prog, user, pass });
```

The modern way by using ProcessBuilder: **thx @Daniel**

```
    String prog = "C:\\program files\\server\\xampp\\mysql\\bin\\mysql";
    String user = "-uroot";
    String pass = "-ppass";

    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(prog, user, pass);
    Process runtimeProcess = builder.start();
    int result = runtimeProcess.waitFor();
    //...
```

Comment: You should use the ProcessBuilder. That's the preferred way to create a process starting from java 1.5. Check [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html)